# TypeError for built-in operation

Tags: rospy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In working with tf.Transformer, I've run into this error many times.

`TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`

The most frustrating part of getting this message is that the traceback blames seemingly random lines of code for the error. Here's one reduced way to get the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('tf')
import tf, rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tfman = tf.Transformer(True, rospy.Duration(10.0))
    angle = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,0)

    m = TransformStamped()
    m.header.frame_id = 'root'
    m.child_frame_id = 'child'
    print type(angle), type(m.transform.rotation)
    m.transform.rotation = angle
    tfman.setTransform(m)

    for i in range(1):
        print i
```

This outputs:

```
 
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/error.py", line 18, in 
    for i in range(1):
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

The clearest way to fix this is to set the rotation using a quaternion, not a numpy array. However, is there some way to get a clearer error message?

Edit: I guess the clearer question is: Why would this mistake cause a TypeError on line 18? Also, I put the error here so that the next person who searches for the error message on the board will find it here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10390/typeerror-for-built-in-operation/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-06-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26578/dany/) on 2016-05-10**:
The error is actually coming from CPython from another thread (so it has nothing to do with the command on line 18).

**Comment by [Dany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26578/dany/) on 2016-05-10**:
This type of print-outs happen in cases when python cannot raise an exception (e.g. if an exception was thrown in **del**).
TypeError *probably* means a non-existing method was called, which makes sense, since you changed the type of m.transform.rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would be better as a [enhancment ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=geometry&type=enhancement&geometry) than a question.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-10-21**:
Has this issue been fixed (link to Trac doesn't work any more)? I had this weird error popping up when trying to use the result of lookupTransform in a message. Took me a while to figure out, what the problem was (sth with the returned tuple).